# Помогите воспроизвеcти структуру sql из имеющихся php исходников

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Имеются плагин форума, но нет таблиц в базе. Решил из исходников сконструировать дамп.

**Исходники**

```
<?php
class forum extends base {
    public $foundRows = 0;
    public $membersWhere = '';

    public function getAllTopics($start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = 'order_index ASC') {
        global $mysql;
        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        $whereQuery = '';

        if ($where != '') {
            $whereQuery = " WHERE " . $where;
        }

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM forum
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_threads WHERE topic_id = forum.id) > 0
            ORDER BY $order
            $limitQuery
        ");


        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = array();
        $whereQuery = '';
        $this->membersQuery = '';

        while($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $return[$d['id']] = $d;

            if ($whereQuery != '') {
                $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
            }

            if ($this->membersQuery != '') {
                $this->membersQuery .= ' OR ';
            }
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }

    public function getAllExistTopics($start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = 'order_index ASC') {
        global $mysql;
        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        $whereQuery = '';

        if ($where != '') {
            $whereQuery = " WHERE " . $where;
        }

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT *,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_threads WHERE topic_id = forum.id) AS nombre_threads
            FROM forum
            $whereQuery
            ORDER BY $order
            $limitQuery
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = array();
        $whereQuery = '';
        $this->membersQuery = '';

        while($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $return[$d['id']] = $d;

            if ($whereQuery != '') {
                $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
            }

            if ($this->membersQuery != '') {
                $this->membersQuery .= ' OR ';
            }
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }

    public function getAllThreads($start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = '') {
        global $mysql;

        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        $whereQuery = '';

        if ($where != '') {
            $whereQuery = " WHERE " . $where;
        }

        $orderQuery = '';

        if ($order != '') {
            $orderQuery = " ORDER BY " . $order;
        }

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT
                th.id,
                th.topic_id,
                th.name AS thread_name,
                th.comment,
                th.datetime,
                th.reply_to,
                th.report_by,
                th.report_reason,
                th.sticky,
                th.locked,
                th.deleted,
                u.member_id,
                COALESCE(nb.dtmax, th.datetime) AS last_message_datetime,
                COALESCE(nb.topic_count, 0) AS topic_count,
                COALESCE(rt.member_id, th.member_id) AS last_message_member_id
            FROM
                forum_threads th
                INNER JOIN members u
                ON th.member_id = u.member_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- date dernière réponse + nombre réponses par thread
                    SELECT
                    reply_to,
                    MAX(datetime) AS dtmax,
                    COUNT(id) AS topic_count
                    FROM forum_threads
                    WHERE reply_to <> 0
                    GROUP BY reply_to
                ) AS nb
                ON th.id = nb.reply_to
                LEFT JOIN forum_threads rt
                ON th.id = rt.reply_to
                AND nb.dtmax = rt.datetime
                LEFT JOIN members lm
                ON rt.member_id = lm.member_id
            $whereQuery
            $orderQuery
            $limitQuery
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = array();
        $whereQuery = '';
        $this->membersQuery = '';

        while($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $return[$d['id']] = $d;

            if ($whereQuery != '') {
                $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
            }

            if ($this->membersQuery != '') {
                $this->membersQuery .= ' OR ';
            }
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }

    public function get($id) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM forum
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return $mysql->fetch_array();
    }

    public function getMemberTotalMessages($id) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT COUNT(id) as total_member_messages
            FROM forum_threads
            WHERE member_id = '" . intval($id) . "'
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return $mysql->fetch_array();
    }

    public function getThread($start = 0, $limit = 0, $id) {
        global $mysql;
        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT ft.*,
            f.name AS topic_name
            FROM forum_threads ft
                LEFT JOIN forum f ON ft.topic_id = f.id
            WHERE
                (ft.id = '" . $id . "' AND ft.name IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                ft.reply_to = '" . $id . "'
            ORDER BY ft.datetime ASC
            $limitQuery
        ", __FUNCTION__ );

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = array();

        while($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $return[$d['id']] = $d;
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }

    public function getThreadTotalMessages($id) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            SELECT COUNT(*) as total_thread_messages
            FROM forum_threads ft
                LEFT JOIN forum f ON ft.topic_id = f.id
            WHERE
                (ft.id = '" . $id . "' AND ft.name IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                ft.reply_to = '" . $id . "'
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return $mysql->fetch_array();
    }

    public function edit($id) {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        if (!isset($_POST['name']) || trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
            $error['name'] = $langArray['error_fill_this_field'];
        }

        if (isset($error)) {
            return $error;
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['visible'])) {
            $_POST['visible'] = 'false';
        }

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum 
            SET name = '" . sql_quote(trim($_POST['name'])) . "',
                name_en = '" . sql_quote(trim($_POST['name_en'])) . "',
                visible = '" . sql_quote($_POST['visible']) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            ", __FUNCTION__
        );

        return true;
    }

    public function add() {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        if (!isset($_POST['name']) || trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
            $error['name'] = $langArray['error_fill_this_field'];
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['name_en']) || trim($_POST['name_en']) == '') {
            $error['name'] = $langArray['error_fill_this_field'];
        }

        if (isset($error)) {
            return $error;
        }

        $orderIndex = $this->getNextOrderIndex();

        $mysql->query("
            INSERT INTO forum (
                name,
                name_en,
                visible,
                order_index
            )
            VALUES (
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['name']) . "',
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['name_en']) . "',
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['visible']) . "',
                '" . intval($orderIndex) . "'
            )
        ", __FUNCTION__ );

        return true;
    }

    public function addThread($replyTo = 0) {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        if (isset($_POST['thread_id'])) {
            $_POST['name'] = '';
            $_POST['subject'] = '';
            $_POST['reply_to'] = $_POST['thread_id'];
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['comment']) || trim($_POST['comment']) == '') {
            $error['comment'] = $langArray['comment'];
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['notify'])) {
            $_POST['notify'] = 'false';
        }

        else {
            $_POST['notify'] = 'true';
        }

        $mysql->query("
            INSERT INTO forum_threads (
                member_id,
                name,
                comment,
                datetime,
                notify,
                reply_to,
                report_by
            )

            VALUES (
                '" . intval($_SESSION['member']['member_id']) . "',
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['subject']) . "',
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['comment']) . "',
                NOW(),
                '" . sql_quote($_POST['notify']) . "',
                '" . sql_quote($replyTo) . "',
                '0'
            )
        ");

        return $mysql->insert_id();
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        global $mysql;

        $row = $this->get($id);

        if (!is_array($row)) {
            return true;
        }

        $mysql->query("
            DELETE FROM forum
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        $mysql->query("
            DELETE FROM forum_threads
            WHERE topic_id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function moderateMessage($id) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET moderate = 'true'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function lockThread($threadID, $locked) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET locked = '" . sql_quote($locked) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($threadID) . "' && reply_to = '0'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function deleteThread($threadID, $deleted) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET deleted = '" . sql_quote($deleted) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($threadID) . "' && reply_to = '0'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function changeSticky($threadID, $sticky) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET sticky = '" . sql_quote($sticky) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($threadID) . "' && reply_to = '0'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function moveThread($threadID, $newTopicID) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET topic_id = '" . intval($newTopicID) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($threadID) . "' && reply_to = '0'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function report($id) {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET report_by = '" . intval($_SESSION['member']['member_id']) . "',
                report_reason = '" . sql_quote($_POST['report_reason']) . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function moderate($id, $comment, $moderate, $name = NULL) {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET name = '" . $name . "',
                comment = '" . $comment . "',
                moderate = '" . $moderate . "'
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function cancelReported($id) {
        global $mysql, $langArray;

        $mysql->query("
            UPDATE forum_threads
            SET report_by = '0',
                report_reason = ''
            WHERE id = '" . intval($id) . "'
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Вот что получилось у меня:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name_en` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visible` enum('true','false') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'false',
  `order_index` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE=MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_threads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `notify` enum('true','false') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'false',
  `reply_to` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `report_by` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Но по моему это не всё, подскажите что еще я упустил?

Comment: Какие признаки того, что вы что-то упустили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну судя по всему еще таблицу members пропустили. Судя по тому что в запросах в приведенном коде используется только member_id дальнейшую структуру можете видимо сделать по вашему усмотрению.

Ну и бы назвал наверное вашу работу воспроизведением структуры, а не дампом, дамп все таки к больше к хранящимся данным относится.